# How to convert code in Visual Basic to C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

This is code in VB.NET:

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        Dim CP As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        CP.Style = &HA0000
        Return CP
    End Get
```

And I want to convert it into C#. As per my assumption below is how the code in C# will look like. For the above code where `CP.Style = &HA000`, what should I put in 
C# code. I have left it empty.

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.Style = 
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Comment: One generic way to do this is to compile the code, then disassemble it in [reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/).  Note that reflector will stop being free *really* soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need:

```
CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
cp.Style = 0xA000;
return cp;
```

`0x` is the prefix for a hex integer literal in C#, instead of `&H` in VB.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
        CreateParams CP = base.CreateParams;
        CP.Style = 0xa0000;
        return CP;
    }
}
```

[Try this convertor](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)

Answer (score 0):

Missing line:

```
cp.Style = 0xA0000;
```